# how can I add multiple values in a single column?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm working on a project and I have a scenario

We have a vendors table, some vendors have many contact no. how can i add multiple phone numbers on a single contact no. column?

Comment: there a lot of solution for example if vendor 1 has contact a and b then you can create two columns first row  1,a second row 1,b

Comment: Ideally you would have a vendors table and a contact table with a Foreign key reference to the vendor table.  I'm not sure of the syntax for MySQL or I would post an answer.

Comment: why you need to put them in a single table, create another table for vendor contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Vendor
(
  Vendor_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  <More_Vendor_Fields>
  ...
  ...
  ...
);



CREATE TABLE Vendor_Contact
(
  Vendor_Contact_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  V_C_Vendor_ID INT,
  Primary_Contact TINYINT(1), -- effectively a Boolean
  Contact_Type CHAR(1), -- you can have (e.g.) L landline, M mobile, O Office, F Factory, C carphone.... Do **NOT** use the ENUM type
  Contact_Number VARCHAR(20),
  <more stuff>
  ...
  CONSTRAINT fk_Vendor_Contact_Vendor FOREIGN KEY (V_C_Vendor_ID)
REFERENCES Vendor(Vendor_ID)
);
```

A couple of notes:

- Always give your `FOREIGN KEY`s meaningful names - it's very difficult to debug a message that tells you that "Constraint XYZ000343A has been violated".
- Don't be tempted to use `ENUM`s - they are [evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) :-). I'm particularly referring here to the Contact_Type field - if there are very many of them, use a (small) reference table - check out the link.
- Do **not** be tempted to do something like using a `VARCHAR(<large_number>)` field and use a comma separated list - this is a recipe for disaster - plus it's a breach of [Codd's Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules) - No. 2.

  - Rule 2: The guaranteed access rule:

  Each and every datum (atomic value) in a relational data base is 
  guaranteed to be logically accessible by resorting to a combination
  of table name, primary key value and column name.

Comment: Ditch the `AUTO_INCREMENT`; instead use `PRIMARY KEY(V_C_Vendor_ID, Primary_Contact, Contact_Type)`.

Comment: I see that you are a purist in the Celko mould? :-) Yes, while natural keys are better in some respects, they lead to complex SQL and performance issues - although this is **hotly** debated. Surrogate keys may be the "easy way out", but I think that the ship has sailed on that one. It's a religious issue - purists vs. pragmatists...

Comment: I had not heard of Celko.  Maybe I should read him.  My focus is usually on performance.  In InnoDB, it is faster to use the PK than a secondary key.  In _this_ situation, `JOIN` will mostly be on `Primary_Contact`.  In _this_ situation, a surrogate key provides no obvious benefit.  (About 30% of _my_ tables have a surrogate key.)

Comment: On many-to-many tables, it is really a waste to include a surrogate.  [my blog on that](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Comment: But it's not a many-many - it's a 1-many. Joe [Celko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko)'s worth reading, even if one doesn't always agree (+ he's a nice chap).

Comment: and what will be the select query to show all contacts of perticular vendor?

Comment: `JOIN` to the table; you will get multiple rows.  Or `JOIN` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` to get a commalist.